# Run "get_the_post_thumbnail" with a different table prefix?

Tags: multisite, wpdb

I have this site were I run two Wordpress sites on the same database (with different prefixes), on one domain.

What I want is to get the post thumbnail from the second Wordpress installation, by running the function `get_the_post_thumbnail` (with a different table prefix), on the first Wordpress installation.

Simplified:

Two Wordpress sites, One database, Wordpress site "a" want to get a post thumbnail from Wordpress site "b" through the function `get_the_post_thumbnail`

I really hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why didn't you use a Network/Multisite install? Problem mainly is that all the queries normally have the current install prefix in use. Without having real access (via `$wpdb`) to the prefix, this will get pretty messy. Actually your problem is a [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

It would be less work to export everything from one of the sites, quickly convert the other site to multisite and then import the data again.

Comment: I see, I will look into this multisite thing! Thanks for the heads-up!